# Nav button disappears when clicked on

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im new to webdesign and im doing this website for a college project. 
So i'm using bootstrap and I got a template called elegance:

[Link](https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524918-elegance-responsive-one-page-html-template)

When I changed the navbar button to call a page i've made, the button simply vanishes, it's still there, I mean, if I hover the mouse over it it'll, but it'll vanish once clicked on.

This was the original which came with the template:

```css
.w-nav-link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.menu-li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.menu-li:hover {
  border-top-style: none;
  background-color: #2fde8f;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-nav navbar" data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" data-contain="1">
  <div class="w-container nav">
    <nav class="w-nav-menu nav-menu" role="navigation">
      <a class="w-nav-link menu-li" href="#home">HOME</a>
      <a class="w-nav-link menu-li" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
      <a class="w-nav-link menu-li" href="#service">SERVICES</a>
      <a class="w-nav-link menu-li" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
      <a class="w-nav-link menu-li"href="#team">TEAM</a>
      <a class="w-nav-link menu-li" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="w-nav-button">
      <div class="w-icon-nav-menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is what I have changed it to:

```css
.w-nav-link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.menu-li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.menu-li:hover {
  border-top-style: none;
  background-color: #2fde8f;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-nav navbar" data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" data-contain="1">
  <div class="w-container nav">
    <nav class="w-nav-menu nav-menu" role="navigation">
      <a class="w-nav-link menu-li" href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a class="w-nav-link menu-li" href="cadastro.html">ABOUT</a>
      <a class="w-nav-link menu-li" href="#service">SERVICES</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="w-nav-button">
      <div class="w-icon-nav-menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, my question is, what should I do to get this button back to normal?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYjaa.jpg)

Comment: Can't reproduce cause the href is invalid. Can you maybe attach a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: +1 on the screenshot suggestion. Is it possible that removing 'color' declaration (was `color: white`) is making the `:active` state seem invisible?

Comment: Ok, i've added a screenshot of it, in the first one you can see the button is not there, but once i hover over it, it'll appear, it'll happen the same thing with the "about" when i'm in its designated page

Comment: are you talking about the "w-nav-button", which only appears on smaller screens? What's the CSS for that, did you change it?

Comment: Will was right, i've removed the "color: white" and it's now working, silly mistake of mine, thanks you guys so much. :D